# Error: Could not find or load main class com.vainolo.JungLearning

Tags: maven

While running the maven project as java application I am getting the following error,

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.vainolo.JungLearning
```

My pom.xml file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ut</groupId>
<artifactId>us</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1</version>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-algorithms</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-jai</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-visualization</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-graph-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-samples</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-jai-samples</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-3d</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-3d-demos</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: This is a pom-file there is no mention of you missing main class. Post more details please

Comment: I appreciate you're just trying to learn Maven. Are you getting the error when you try to run your project from your IDE? Are you able to navigate to the JungLearning class?

Comment: Thanks all.I am successfully able to run maven project